# pydispatch module installed but still couldn't be found

Tags: python, module, installation, raspberry-pi, scrapy

I tried to install scrapy on my raspberry pi (raspbian os). The installation went okay, but when I run `scrapy` command, it showed that several modules are missing. So I installed them one by one:
`sudo pip install lxml', then 'sudo pip install cssselect'. Then 'sudo pip install pydispatch`. The problem I am having now is that, even the `pydispatch` seemed to be installed successfully, the `scrapy` still could not find it. Below is a screenshot of my terminal. How should I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package's name is [PyDispatcher](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDispatcher). So try installing it using this command and check if that works.

```
pip install PyDispatcher
```

Problems during installation of scrapy varies on different platforms. Please share your solution if you could successfully install this.

Comment: It worked! I just 'startproject ' and everything is fine so far. Thank you @salman!